# Probability for sum of events greater than 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory

When two events, A and B, are mutually exclusive, the probability that A or B will occur is the sum of the probability of each event. 
The same thing we could say about sum of A, B and C.

In several articles I found another definition of the sum:

When two events, A and B, are mutually exclusive, the probability that **A or B or *A and B*** will occur is the sum of the probability of each event.

**First question:** Is second definition correct?

For second question let imagine the following example:

Probability of getting tail of the coin is 1/2. Person throws coin 3 times.

- Event A: get tail at first throw, P(A) = 1/2
- Event B: get tail at second throw, P(B) = 1/2
- Event C: get tail at third throw, P(C) = 1/2

Then probability of getting tail at first or second or third throw is:

P(A + B + C) = 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 = 3/2, **but 3/2 > 1**

But as we know probability P of event is always 0 <= P <= 1

**Second question:** Where am I wrong?

Comment: Addition of probabilities is only correct if at most one event can happen. This is not the case here.

Comment: @Peter Could you also said which of the sum definitions is correct?

Comment: For two events , you have $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$ To get the formula for three events just use $P(A\cup B\cup C)=P((A\cup B)\cup C)$

Comment: In your case, it is much easier to calculate the probability that no throw is tails (it is $\frac{1}{8}$). So, the desired probability is $1-\frac{1}{8}=\frac{7}{8}$.

Comment: Check out the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability)

Comment: @Peter Thank you, but I'm talking about sum definition. In words: when two events, A and B, are mutually exclusive, the probability that A or B or **A and B** will occur is the sum of the probability of each event. Is bold part is correct?

Comment: @NoNameYp Yes, this is the correct definition of "or".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:  Yes, the definition is correct. If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then: $$P(A \cap B)=0$$ and: $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$$ and so indeed we have that: $$P(A \cup B \cup (A \cap B))=P(A) + P(B)$$

Second question: Your events are not mutually exclusive, and so you cannot add up the probabilities: you can only use $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$$ when $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive. And your events are not mutually exclusive because any two of them can happen in the same scenario. In fact, they can all three happen: you throw a tail for all three tosses.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Then What formula should I use to calculate probability of getting at least one tail from my original question?

Comment: @NoNameYp Getting at least one tail is the same as not getting $0$ tails. So, calculate the probability of getting $0$ tails, and subtract that from $1$.  Since $A$, $B$, and $C$ are *independent* (that is, geting a tail on the first toss does not effect the probability of getting a tail on the second or third toss, etc.), you have that $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(C)$

Comment: One more question: When two events, A and B, are independent, the probability that A or B  will occur is P(A+B) = ??

Comment: @NoNameYp It is *always* true that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, so when $A$ and $B$ are independent, we have $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)-P(A)\cdot P(B)$

Comment: I'm really sorry, I meant word "dependent". So the right question will be: When two events, A and B, are dependent, the probability that A or B will occur is P(A+B) = ??

Comment: @NoNameYp Then we have $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) -P(A \cap B)$ ... for that is *always* true, whether $A$ and $B$ are dependent or independent, and whether they are mutually exclusive or not.

Comment: The very last question: according to all your answers I suppose that independent and not mutually exclusive events are the same thing. Is it true?

Comment: @NoNameYp Well, if events are mutually exclusive they are dependent ... unless both have a probability of $0$. So, if independent, then not mutually exclusive. But, not being mutually exclusive does not mean independent. Indeed, any event is not mutually exclusive with itself, but certainly not independent from itself. So no, they are not the same thing.